# How do we send a PDF file (which we have path of) to get printed directly without confirmation dialogs?

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, printing, pdfdocument

I am super new to Kotlin app development and I am trying to make an app which generates & sends a PDF to print directly to the once chosen printer... I'm using `PdfDocument` library to generate a PDF using my `printPDF` function -

```
//necessary imports

private fun generatePDF(text: String) {
    val fileName = "badge.pdf"
    val pdfDocument = PdfDocument()
    val pageInfo = PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(288, 432, 1).create()

    // .... pdf building code here

    val downloadsDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    val badgesDir = File(downloadsDir, "Badges")
    if (!badgesDir.exists()) {
        badgesDir.mkdirs()
    }
    val file = File(badgesDir, fileName)
    pdfDocument.writeTo(file.outputStream())
    pdfDocument.close()

    Toast.makeText(this, "success: ${file.path}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    //toast prints like - "success: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Badges/badge.pdf"
}
```

The above `generatePDF` function creates & stores the PDF in/as `Download > Badges > badge.pdf`, which I can access by going into the Download folder in my phone's file manager.

After the toast, I want to send it directly to the printer to get printed, without any page-setup/confirmation/customisation dialogs intervening the process. It would be like I choose the printer once & for all at the very first print, and then it should just directly print the document without asking for choosing printers. So far I've read some stuff about `PrintDocumentAdapter`, but can't wrap my head around it if it's the one I want and how to implement it....

Is this possible to do in Kotlin, sending a document to be directly printed?

Comment: Check if mkdir() does its job:     if (!badgesDir.exists()) {
        if(!badgesDir.mkdirs()) return;
    }

Comment: `stores the PDF in/as Download > Badges > badge.pdf` ? Are you a programmer? /storage/emulated/0/Download/Badges/badge.pdf we assume.

Comment: Please post also the print code where the user has to confirm first.

Comment: Hi @blackapps, thanks for replying.... **1)** My code works perfectly for generating pdfs, nothing to check about there. **2)** I am a programmer, I just thought I'd elaborate more :) **3)** At the moment my code is only till generating PDFs, and it works perfectly, I am yet to build further... This is just an app i am making for myself, not releasing publicly. I just wanted to know whether it's possible to send a document to print directly and how to do it.... Thanks!

Comment: The Android SDK does not have anything for direct printing without user involvement. You would need to determine how to do that from your printer manufacturer.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, thanks for replying. What kind of involvement would it be? Can we at-least set a printer as the default for every print and the user just clicks print or confirm instead of choosing printer everytime like we have to normally? Please advice. Thanks!

Comment: "Can we at-least set a printer as the default for every print and the user just clicks print or confirm instead of choosing printer everytime like we have to normally?" -- there is no means programmatically to do that. Whether there is some option in the UI for that would be up to Google and/or device manufacturers, and users would have to opt in for that.